# Why is in Magento the advanced date still in m/d/y format?

Tags: magento

I have installed the Dutch language pack, setup Dutch store, set the locale Options to **W. Europe Standard Time (Berlin)**, set the locale to Dutch, set the date fields order to day/month/year and when searching on date in advanced search it is still required to enter date value in m/d/y where I like to have d/m/y.

**What have I forgotten?**

Comment: Are you using a default or a customize  magento theme/template (on advanced search)?... View page source in your browser and look at the validation classname on that date field... http://blog.magestore.com/2010/04/09/magestore-magento-tutorial-form-validation-in-magento/

Comment: I am using template as default... so its template issue.

Ok, I will check.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Is your Magento cache refreshed? If block-html output is cached, you may not see changes.

Comment: Yes, I am in the middle of setting up website, so Cache refresh is standard :-)

I am really confused about this. Everything is Dutch, it wants the NL.XML where the short date is setup, but it still wants m/d/y